# Display Message on redirect?

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm making a page where you input info and click "Install" and then it goes to a file named "install_submit.php". I have it redirecting back to the form page when there is missing information display the message "Missing Information"!

this is my current code for "install_submit.php".

```
<?php
$dbname = $_POST['db_name'];
$dbuser = $_POST['db_user'];
$dbpass = $_POST['db_pass'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($dbname) || empty($dbuser) || empty($dbpass) || empty($username) || empty($password))
{
header("Location: install.php");
Echo("Missing Information!");
}else{
Echo("Success!");
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not show the _"Missing Information!"_ message on `install.php`?

Answer (score 2):

Save it in a session and display it in your form location.

```
$_SESSION['error_message'] = "Missing Information!";
```

And in your form location:

```
<p class="errors"><?php if (!empty($_SESSION['error_message']) echo $_SESSION['error_message']; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the url in header and pass a parameter for example

`header("Location: install.php?submit=false");`

then in your "install_submit.php" you can get the info

```
if($_GET['submit'] == 'false') {
  echo("Missing Information!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a session variable, like so:

```
session_start();
if(empty($dbname) || empty($dbuser) || empty($dbpass) || empty($username) || empty($password))
{
    $_SESSION["error_message"] = "Missing Information!";
    header("Location: install.php");
}else{
    unset($_SESSION["error_message"]);
    echo "Success!";
}
```

Then, on install.php reference the session variable somewhere like this:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION["error_message"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["error_message"];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do a redirect and don't use a separate url for processing. Handle the form submit on the same page. You don't want your user to provide all the information *again*.

You could redirect to `install.php?error=true&db_name=...&db_user=...` but it's just more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

After you redirect, you will no longer be able to output from the current page. This is why your echo("missing information!"); does not do anything at the moment.

You could try setting the error message in a session, and then check if the error-session is populated on the form page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['errmsg'] = "Missing information!";
header("Location: install.php");
```

and then in your install.php:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['errmsg'])) {
echo $_SESSION['errmsg'];
unset($_SESSION['errmsg']);
}
```

Comment: "After you redirect, you will no longer be able to output from the current page." - not true, you are able to output, the web-server will send it to the client but he will never see it.

Comment: Duncan - I am glad to hear it! Remember to mark one of the correct answers as the solution. @yi_H - I was simplifying it for the OP, thank you for your input.